# How to set background color for a paragraph in MS Word 2003

Tags: ms-word, background-color

Is there an easy way to change the background color of a single paragraph in a MS Word (2003) document?

Comment: Ask this at superuser.com as that is for non-programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can place that paragraph in a single table cell and then set the background color and border colors of that table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select (highlight) the paragraph;
2. From **Tables and Borders** toolbar, click the arrow next to Shading Color Button [image].
3. Select your favorate color to fill the backgroud of that paragraph.